# Post fields and a file using the new System.Net.WebClient

Tags: c#, file-upload, webclient, system.net, form-post

i'm trying to invoke a webapi with the new System.Net.WebClient and didnot found any special examples.

The goal is simulate a traditional form post with some fields and a file.

how can i do it using the System.Net.WebClient or where can i find some examples?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of examples if you do a fast google search, anyway, here goes some samples:

Simple GET

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json"; //setting headers

string json = webClient.DownloadString(url);
```

Simple POST

```
NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
values["user"] = username;
values["pwd"] = password;
webClient.UploadValues(url, values);
```

There's also an UploadData that sends byte arrays and UploadFile that allows you to upload files directly from disk.

Comment: my question is not about the simple get or simple post, is about do a post like a multipart/form-data form, where is possible to send in the same request, a file and a couple of KeyValue fields

Comment: I didn't find a suitable implementation in WebClient. Probably it's only possible through HttpWebRequest. Unfortunately the WebClient isn't a complete implementation. I had troubles with some other issue like using cookies, for example.

Comment: I'd make an extension method for that.