# how to make http request GET to API with authorization in C#?

Tags: c#, get, authorization, httprequest

I'm new to programming and I have troubles with the task. I write unit test where I need to connect to our API with HTTP request and then call a method "create" (for example). I need to get responce and verify that "package" created by the method is of int type. I tried to use HttpRequest class but got stuck. Could somebody help with example, please?

Comment: Maybe post some code so we can see what's wrong?

Comment: Did you try WebClient? This question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738839/post-fields-and-a-file-using-the-new-system-net-webclient/24741208#24741208